# How to detect div tag area when user scroll in react functional components?

Tags: reactjs

I need a solution like this [https://codepen.io/BraisC/pen/mxVwVm][1]

I want to create that using react functional component by using react hooks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add event listener to scroll on useEffect and in that callback you can update the current active section:

[Check here I've implemented this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-s9fxhp?file=src/App.js)

```js
const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);

    return () => window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
  }, []);

  const handleScroll = () => {
    if (window.pageYOffset <= 935 && index !== 0) {
      setIndex(0);
    } else if (
      window.pageYOffset > 935 &&
      window.pageYOffset <= 1870 &&
      index !== 1
    ) {
      setIndex(1);
    } else if (window.pageYOffset > 1870 && index !== 2) {
      setIndex(2);
    } else {
      setIndex(0);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <nav className="nav">
        <ul className="menu">
          <li
            className={index === 0 ? 'active' : ''}
            onClick={() => setIndex(0)}
          >
            <a href="#home">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li
            className={index === 1 ? 'active' : ''}
            onClick={() => setIndex(1)}
          >
            <a href="#main">Main</a>
          </li>
          <li
            className={index === 2 ? 'active' : ''}
            onClick={() => setIndex(2)}
          >
            <a href="#about">About</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <div id="home" className="section1 section" />
      <div id="main" className="section2 section" />
      <div id="about" className="section3 section" />
    </div>
  );
```

And I will suggest to use throttling to limit the number of events triggered.

Comment: wow nice, it's working and clean coding and I appreciate it. 